# Column displays each count

Tags: sql, oracle, multiple-columns

I am trying to run a query to count records based on a time stamp year to year. Here is a query that I currently have:

```
SELECT plocation AS GROUP_NUMBER, count(DISTINCT UMEMBERID) AS YEAR_ONE
    FROM HEALTH_ASSESSMENT
    WHERE PUBLICATIONDT > '31-DEC-13'AND PUBLICATIONDT < '01-JAN-15'
    GROUP BY PLOCATION
```

It counts exactly what I need for the time frame and displays the following:

```
GROUP_NUMBER | YEAR_ONE

G12345       |      141
G12346       |       61
```

Where `YEAR_ONE` is the dates I've listed, which is essentially 2014. Is there a way to create an additional column that counts a second time frame? For example, something like this:

```
GROUP_NUMBER |   YEAR_ONE     | YEAR_TWO 

G12345       |       141      |     92    
G12346       |       61       |     57
G12444       |  NULL OR BLANK |     16
```

Here `G12444` may not have any records in the `YEAR_ONE` parameters, but would have records in the `YEAR TWO` parameters. Sometimes this query would be on a month to month basis so having each column be setup with the parameters of `01-JAN-15 - 31-JAN-15` may also be needed as well.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a CASE statement.  Something like this should work:

```
SELECT plocation AS GROUP_NUMBER
    , count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN EXTRACT( YEAR from PUBLICATIONDT) = 2014 THEN UMEMBERID ELSE null END) AS YEAR_ONE
    , count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN EXTRACT( YEAR from PUBLICATIONDT) = 2015 THEN UMEMBERID ELSE null END) AS YEAR_two
    FROM HEALTH_ASSESSMENT
    WHERE EXTRACT( YEAR from PUBLICATIONDT) BETWEEN 2014 and 2015       
GROUP BY PLOCATION
```

Comment: It's should be `... AND PUBLICATIONDT < '01-JAN-16'` since you include `CASE WHEN YEAR(PUBLICATIONDT) = 2015` in query.

Comment: Updated the year in the case statements.

Comment: How about `PUBLICATIONDT > '31-DEC-13'`? You should change `where` clause. Because it's eliminated all years except 2014.

Comment: I think It's should works. Just wait for op response and +1 to your answer.

Comment: I think we are getting close! The format for the publicationdt is 2/24/2014 3:03:37 PM; so it's giving me an error that YEAR is an invalid identifier.

Comment: Ah, yes, this is Oracle, so its slightly different.  Try it with the EXTRACT(YEAR from X) syntax.

Comment: Another question, how could I do the same query but break down each column by month? So a column for each month and year, for example: Jan,2014; Feb,2014; Mar,2014 so on and so forth.

Comment: Well, your query will start getting rather long and difficult to maintain, but you can just add more case statements.  CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR from PUBLICATIONDT) = 2014 and EXTRACT(MONTH from PUBLICATIONDT) = 1 THEN ...